# Cannot connect to windows share using computer name

Tags: windows-7, samba

I have Ubuntu 12.10 installed in VMware Workstation as a guest. The VM's network adapter is set up as "bridge", so effectively, it should look like it is connected directly to the switch all my computers are connected to.

I am trying to make the VM connect to shares on the host. The host has a computer name of `MyComp` and workgroup of `WORKGROUP`. The host is running Windows 7 64-bit.

In Nautilus, I choose `File > Connect to server`. I then set it to `Windows Share` and try to connect to my computer. If I set `MyComp` as the server name, the connection will fail with `Failed to retrieve share list from server`. If I set it to the ip address `192.168.1.7`, then it works.

I have done a bit of research and discovered that maybe it is because I don't have `nmbd` installed on the system. However, I believe it is part of the samba packages, which I do have:

```
user@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install samba-common-bin smbclient samba-common
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
samba-common is already the newest version.
smbclient is already the newest version.
samba-common-bin is already the newest version.
```

Is there anyway I can connect to the windows share using the computer name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found a solution to this after fiddling with some other things.

1. Install Winbind if it has not been installed:

   sudo aptitude install winbind
2. Edit `/etc/nsswitch.conf` and change `hosts: files dns` to `hosts: files wins dns`.

You may after to restart your system after changing this.